# Load jQuery so that bots can see the results

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not a actual programmer, just a curious project manager, so please bear with me :)

I have a "small" problem with a menu that I want to use on my site
I use a jQuery script to load a separate file with the menu (I use the menu on a lot of pages and I don't want to apply the changes on every page)

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function () {
     $("#includedMenu").load("/upload/Menu.html");
   });
</script>
```

And to show it I use this:

```
id="includedMenu"
```

It works just fine, but the code seems to be generated after the page has been loaded
And as i recall, the search engine bots will not index my menu, and, for me, that is essential.

Does anybody have any idea how I can get around it? 
I don't have access to the source code, the site is based on a N2 CMS so I can only access a HTML editor

Comment: You would need to be able to detect that the current "viewer" of the content is a web scraper and display the appropriate content. I don't think you'll be able to do this without modifying server side code.

Comment: I think you could add a real link (<a> tag) in your page that points towards your menu.html file and then move it off screen with css. I think bots might want to follow that and end on your menu page and from there on follow other links

Answer (score -2):

## 1: not sure why you have menu in a .html file vs. a .css file

Regardless, try loading your menu in the .ready(), which will fire as soon as the DOM has been fully constructed.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#includedMenu").load("/upload/Menu.html");
});
```

There are limits on what you can do, if you don't have access to the source code, but try this change; it should help.

To test that the menu is loading before page displays, add an alert before the closing script tag :

```
alert("menu loaded");
```

Comment: Fyi...$(document).ready() and $(function(){ ... }) are the exact same thing.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work, but is there a way to test it? I mean,  it looks just fine, but how do I know that the content is loaded the right way?

Comment: Some bots don't use javascript at all, so I think this won't work